# Determine the Kernel of $f$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Given the mapping:

$f$ : $Z → S_4$,  $f(n)$ = $(1234)^n$ determine the kernel of $f$

So my original thoughts were that the kernel is $(4)$ as $f((4))$ = $0$

But I'm  not sure on how to prove this.

Comment: The kernel of a group homomorphism is **always** a (normal) subgroup of the domain group. It can't be one element...

Comment: Good start. Is 4 the only value for which f(4) = 0? (side note on notation, \mathbb{Z} giving $\mathbb{Z}$ is typically used for the integers)

Comment: @DonAntonio Yeah see I know this too, this is why I've gotten confused because $Z$ is infinite, so my other thought was it to be $(4)$

Comment: @B.Mehta Sorry by $4$ i actually meant $(4)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you surmise that $\text{ker }f$ might be $4\Bbb Z = (4)$.

You note correctly that $f(4\Bbb Z) = \{\text{id}\}$, since:

$f(4k) = (1\ 2\ 3\ 4)^{4k} = [(1\ 2\ 3\ 4)^4]^k = (\text{id})^k = \text{id}$.

This shows $4\Bbb Z \subseteq \text{ker }f$.

Now show that if $f(n) = \text{id}$, that $4|n$ and you're done, as this shows $\text{ker }f \subseteq 4\Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
The neutral element o $S_4$ is the identical permutation, so it is defined as
$$\ker  f=\{n\mid f(n)= \operatorname{id}\}$$
Now $$(1234)^2=(13)(24),\quad(1234)^3=(1432), \quad (1234)^4=\operatorname{id},$$
so that $\;(1234)^n=(1234)^{n\bmod 4}$.

Answer (score 0):

For every group $G$ and every $g\in G$, the map
$$
\varphi_g\colon\mathbb{Z}\to G,
\qquad
\varphi_g(n)=g^n
$$
is a homomorphism and its image is the smallest subgroup of $G$ containing $g$, that is,
$$
\varphi_g(\mathbb{Z})=\langle g\rangle=\{g^n:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}
$$
If $G$ is finite, then also $\langle g\rangle$ is finite. By the homomorphism theorems,
$$
\varphi_g(\mathbb{Z})=\langle g\rangle\cong\mathbb{Z}/\ker\varphi_g
$$
Since every subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ has the form $k\mathbb{Z}$, for a unique $k\ge0$, we have $\ker\varphi_g=k\mathbb{Z}$. In this case $k>0$ and, since $|\mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z}|=k$, we have
$$
k=|\langle g\rangle|
$$
Moreover $\varphi_g(k)=g^k=1$ (because $k\in\ker\varphi_g$) and, for $0<r<k$, $\varphi_g(r)=g^r\ne 1$ (because $r\notin\ker\varphi_g$).

Therefore $k$ is the *order* of $g$.

In the case $G=S_4$ and $g=(1234)$, what is the order of $g$?